# SharePoint AddIn, can't find "Style Library"? Language Issue

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, pnp-js

I have an AddIn that works fine to install in an English setup of Sharepoint. However, when I test this in another language I run into an issue.

The issue is with this code:

```
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Style Library");
```

I get the error that the list "Style Library" can't be found on the site https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/Testsite.

How can I do this in another way without being language dependent?
I've tried to search everywhere but can't find a way.
Is this something to do with "Metadata Language"? Can that be changed for an AddIn?

Comment: have  you tried to use var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Style%20Library"); because sometimes I get issues with list names when they got spaces, so I use the replace of the space which is %20 or if it is a custom list or library i use (_) instead of space when i create it, try to paste the response message of the xhr that could help helpers to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the language issue, we can use web.get_lists().getById method to achieve it.

```
var list = web.get_lists().getById('xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx');
```